How to listen to scroll events in GTKMM 4?
I have the following example, where I create a simple window with a scrollbar and a scroll event controller that connects the onScroll member function to handle the events:
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

class ScrollingWindow : public Gtk::Window {
    Gtk::Scrollbar scrollbar;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Adjustment> adjustment;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::EventControllerScroll> eventControllerScroll;

public:

    ScrollingWindow() {
        set_default_size(600, 100);
        adjustment = Gtk::Adjustment::create(0, 0, 100, 1);
        eventControllerScroll = Gtk::EventControllerScroll::create();
        eventControllerScroll->signal_scroll().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ScrollingWindow::onScroll), true);
        scrollbar.set_adjustment(adjustment);
        scrollbar.add_controller(eventControllerScroll);

        set_child(scrollbar);
    }

    bool onScroll(double dx, double dy) {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("hu.azsn.animation");
    return app->make_window_and_run<ScrollingWindow>(argc, argv);
}

Unfortunately, I don't get any output in the terminal when I scroll the scrollbar. What do I miss?
Class reference that I checked:
Gtk::EventControllerScroll::signal_scroll. It doesn't specify what the second bool argument should be, I tried both.

#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

class ScrollingWindow : public Gtk::Window {
    Gtk::Scrollbar scrollbar;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Adjustment> adjustment;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::EventControllerScroll> eventControllerScroll;

public:
    ScrollingWindow() {
        set_default_size(600, 100);
        adjustment = Gtk::Adjustment::create(0, 0, 100, 1);
        eventControllerScroll = Gtk::EventControllerScroll::create();
        
        // Connect the scroll signal to the handler function
        eventControllerScroll->signal_scroll().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ScrollingWindow::onScroll), false);

        scrollbar.set_adjustment(adjustment);
        
        // Add the controller to the window instead of the scrollbar
        add_controller(eventControllerScroll);

        set_child(scrollbar);
    }

    bool onScroll(double dx, double dy) {
        std::cout << "Scroll event detected. dx: " << dx << ", dy: " << dy << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("hu.azsn.animation");
    return app->make_window_and_run<ScrollingWindow>(argc, argv);
}


Thank you, I've just tried it, unfortunately, still no output.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

My trials examples like this work, but I am not expert. This code can replace "keyboard_event/simple" examplewindow.cc with mouse events.
in https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtkmm-documentation/chapter-keyboardevents.html
#include "examplewindow.h"
#include <iostream>

ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()
{
  set_title("Keyboard: Alt, Shift, Ctrl, Meta, Mouse move, Mouse click, Mouse scroll Events");
  m_container.set_margin(10);
  set_child(m_container);

  // Radio buttons:
  m_first.set_label("First (Alt+a)");
  m_second.set_label("Second (Alt+b)");

  m_second.set_group(m_first);
  m_first.set_active();

  // Main Container:
  m_container.set_orientation(Gtk::Orientation::HORIZONTAL);
  m_container.append(m_first);
  m_container.append(m_second);

  //add_events (GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH );

  // Events.
  auto controller = Gtk::EventControllerKey::create();
  controller->signal_key_pressed().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_window_key_pressed), false);
  add_controller(controller);


  auto controller1 = Gtk::EventControllerMotion::create();
  controller1->signal_motion().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_Mouse_Motion), false);
  add_controller(controller1);

  auto controller2 = Gtk::EventControllerKey::create();
  controller2->signal_modifiers().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_Modifiers), false);
  add_controller(controller2);

    auto controller3 = Gtk::EventControllerScroll::create();
    controller3->set_flags(Gtk::EventControllerScroll::Flags::VERTICAL);
      controller3->set_propagation_phase(Gtk::PropagationPhase::CAPTURE);
    controller3->signal_scroll().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_scroll), false);
  add_controller(controller3);

  auto mouse = Gtk::GestureClick::create();
  mouse->set_propagation_phase(Gtk::PropagationPhase::CAPTURE);
  mouse->set_button(GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY);
  mouse->signal_pressed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_mb1pressed), false);
  add_controller(mouse);

  auto mouse1 = Gtk::GestureClick::create();
  mouse1->set_propagation_phase(Gtk::PropagationPhase::CAPTURE);
  mouse1->set_button(GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY);
  mouse1->signal_released().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_mb1released), false);
  add_controller(mouse1);

    auto mouse2 = Gtk::GestureClick::create();
  mouse2->set_propagation_phase(Gtk::PropagationPhase::CAPTURE);
  mouse2->set_button(GDK_BUTTON_MIDDLE);
  mouse2->signal_pressed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_mb2pressed), false);
  add_controller(mouse2);

  auto mouse3 = Gtk::GestureClick::create();
  mouse3->set_propagation_phase(Gtk::PropagationPhase::CAPTURE);
  mouse3->set_button(GDK_BUTTON_MIDDLE);
  mouse3->signal_released().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_mb2released), false);
  add_controller(mouse3);

    auto mouse4 = Gtk::GestureClick::create();
  mouse4->set_propagation_phase(Gtk::PropagationPhase::CAPTURE);
  mouse4->set_button(GDK_BUTTON_SECONDARY);
  mouse4->signal_pressed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_mb3pressed), false);
  add_controller(mouse4);

  auto mouse5 = Gtk::GestureClick::create();
  mouse5->set_propagation_phase(Gtk::PropagationPhase::CAPTURE);
  mouse5->set_button(GDK_BUTTON_SECONDARY);
  mouse5->signal_released().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_mb3released), false);
  add_controller(mouse5);
}

bool ExampleWindow::on_scroll(double dx, double dy)
{
    std::cout << "on_scroll: "  << dx << ", "<< dy << std::endl;
return true;
 }

bool ExampleWindow::on_Modifiers(Gdk::ModifierType state)
{
  if ((state & Gdk::ModifierType::SHIFT_MASK)  == Gdk::ModifierType::SHIFT_MASK)
  {
    std::cout << "_SHIFT" << std::endl;
        return true;
  }
  if ((state & Gdk::ModifierType::CONTROL_MASK)  == Gdk::ModifierType::CONTROL_MASK)
  {
    std::cout << "_CTRL" << std::endl;
        return true;
  }
  if ((state & Gdk::ModifierType::ALT_MASK)  == Gdk::ModifierType::ALT_MASK)
  {
    std::cout << "_ALT" << std::endl;
        return true;
  }
  if ((state & Gdk::ModifierType::META_MASK)  == Gdk::ModifierType::META_MASK)
  {
    std::cout << "_META" << std::endl;
        return true;
  }

return false;
}

void ExampleWindow::on_mb1pressed(int n_press, double x, double y)
{
std::cout << "on_mb1Pressed: " << n_press << ", " << x << ", "<< y << std::endl;

}

void ExampleWindow::on_mb1released(int n_press, double x, double y)
{
std::cout << "on_mb1Released: " << n_press << ", " << x << ", "<< y << std::endl;
}

void ExampleWindow::on_mb2pressed(int n_press, double x, double y)
{
std::cout << "on_mb2Pressed: " << n_press << ", " << x << ", "<< y << std::endl;
}

void ExampleWindow::on_mb2released(int n_press, double x, double y)
{
std::cout << "on_mb2Released: " << n_press << ", " << x << ", "<< y << std::endl;
}

void ExampleWindow::on_mb3pressed(int n_press, double x, double y)
{
std::cout << "on_mb3Pressed: " << n_press << ", " << x << ", "<< y << std::endl;
}

void ExampleWindow::on_mb3released(int n_press, double x, double y)
{
std::cout << "on_mb3Released: " << n_press << ", " << x << ", "<< y << std::endl;
}


void ExampleWindow::on_Mouse_Motion(double x, double y)
{
std::cout << "on_Mouse_Motion: "  << x << ", "<< y << std::endl;
}

bool ExampleWindow::on_window_key_pressed(guint keyval, guint, Gdk::ModifierType state)
{
  //Gdk::ModifierType::ALT_MASK -> the 'Alt' key(mask)
  //GDK_KEY_1 -> the '1' key
  //GDK_KEY_2 -> the '2' key

  //select the first radio button, when we press alt + 1
  if((keyval == GDK_KEY_a) &&
    (state & (Gdk::ModifierType::SHIFT_MASK | Gdk::ModifierType::CONTROL_MASK | Gdk::ModifierType::ALT_MASK)) == Gdk::ModifierType::ALT_MASK)
  {
    m_first.set_active();
    //returning true, cancels the propagation of the event
    return true;
  }
  else if((keyval == GDK_KEY_b) &&
    (state & (Gdk::ModifierType::SHIFT_MASK | Gdk::ModifierType::CONTROL_MASK | Gdk::ModifierType::ALT_MASK)) == Gdk::ModifierType::ALT_MASK)
  {
    //and the second radio button, when we press alt + 2
    m_second.set_active();
    return true;
  }
  else if(keyval == GDK_KEY_Escape)
  {
    //close the window, when the 'esc' key is pressed
    set_visible(false);
    return true;
  }


  //the event has not been handled
  return false;
}

ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow()
{
}



